# Varchar to number conversion for sorting

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a query ordered by `column`:

```
select * from mytable order by column asc — sort table
```

`column` type is varchar, so the output is:

```
1
10
100
11
12
13
```

How should I sort if I want them to sort by numeric value so the output is:

```
1
10
11
12
13
100
```

Comment: explain your question better. And why isn't working for you.

Comment: It's not working because the column's a varchar and he wants to sort by the numerical value. Wasn't that hard...

Answer (score 60):

Use:

```
order by cast(column as unsigned) asc
```

Comment: Can anyone explain why this AS INT doesn't work, but UNSIGNED does?

Answer (score 33):

You can use this if you want to treat `column` as `INT` only:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY column+0;
1
10
11
12
13
100
```

Or this if you want to treat `column` as both `INT` and `VARCHAR`

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY column+0, column; #this will sort the column by VARCHAR first and then sort it by INT

abc
xyz
1
10
11
12
13
100
```

Comment: If you want to sort desc :
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY column+0 DESC, column DESC;

Answer (score 13):

This should work as well:

```
order by (0 + column) asc
```

Comment: Very clever. Which one do you think will perform better?

Comment: I don't know the performance implications of this compared to Pablo's answer. If anyone knows, I'd like to know.

Comment: What is the significance of adding 0 to column ?

Comment: Using cast, the MySQL engine knows you want to convert to integer for sorting. Using addition, MySQL thinks you need to perform some generic calculations ( same as -1/sqrt(column)*log column^2 ) before sorting, while you just need a simple conversion. So I guess the first option is faster, as it can optimize exactly for what you need.

Comment: @RajivPingale adding 0 to a *string* converts the string to an integer: "123"+0=123 thus the result is integer and sorted as such, so 10 goes after 2, while "10" is before "2" (alphabetically)

Comment: @FrancescoMM Ohh... Thanks for adding something in my knowledge, I never know that :)

Answer (score 12):

If we simply modify the order by declaration slightly (add “+0″ to the order by field), you can force MySQL to sort the field naturally.

```
 > select * from mytable order by column+0 asc;
 column
 1 
 10
 11
 12
 13 
 100
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    Added a full code script here , but need to sort 1001 and 1002 before - as well.
We have total 5 solution , means 5 different queries as solution with full script.


=============================================================
    SET NAMES utf8;
    SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
    SET time_zone = 'SYSTEM';
    SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `varchar_sort`;
    CREATE TABLE `varchar_sort` (
      `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `actual_user_id` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    INSERT INTO `varchar_sort` (`user_id`, `actual_user_id`) VALUES
    (1, '1001-4'),
    (2, '1001-1'),
    (3, '1001-111'),
    (4, '1002-1'),
    (5, '1001-66'),
    (6, '1001-100'),
    (7, '1001-110');


    SELECT user_id,actual_user_id,CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(actual_user_id,'-',-1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS num
    FROM varchar_sort
    ORDER BY num;


    SELECT user_id,actual_user_id
    FROM varchar_sort
    ORDER BY CONVERT(SUBSTRING(actual_user_id, 6), SIGNED INTEGER);


    SELECT user_id,actual_user_id
    FROM varchar_sort
    ORDER BY CONVERT(SUBSTRING(actual_user_id, LOCATE('-', actual_user_id) + 1), SIGNED INTEGER);


    SELECT *, CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(actual_user_id, '-', -1) AS UNSIGNED) as num FROM varchar_sort ORDER BY num;
```

select * from varchar_sort order by convert( replace(actual_user_id, '-',''), SIGNED INTEGER ) asc

```
    **Need to sort 1001 and 1002 as well.**
```

Comment: @SuperFamousGuy It is a good answer but it is just relevant but not targets the OPs question