# mysql Max behaviour with numeric vals in varchar field

Tags: mysql, max

We have a database table that has keys and values where the value can be anything in a varchar field.  The values are for attributes about an item and one attribute is price.

To make a select field for prices, I was using the `Max()` function to find the greatest value in the value column which seemed to work.

Then when we got prices over £100, they started to not get returned as the max value.  I under stand that this is because it is a string value and not numeric.

The confusion comes when running a command like `select max(value) from attributes where value > 100`  because now the statement recognises that 101 is > 100 but 99 is not so returns 101 as the max value, however without the `where value > 100` clause, 99 is treated as > 101.  Why does the > 100 clause work as a numeric comparison but max does not?

Is there a reason that this happens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [varchar to number conversion for sorting in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868965/varchar-to-number-conversion-for-sorting-in-mysql). Do not mixed varchar with numeric, you can do the same `max( cast(value as unsigned) )` but is no ideal

Comment: great thanks mate, if you put that in an answer I can accept it.  Or should I just close the question as its pretty much a duplicate.  Do you know why the > clause works? that was the real reason for the question.

Comment: @Luke without type conversion `>` clause doesn't work too. Try: `select '1000' > '99'`

Comment: This statment: `select max(value) from attributes where value > 100` did work though, thats what confused us, but `select max(value) from attributes where value > 50` did not, it still selected 99 as the greatest value.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do not mixed varchar with numeric,
idea solution is only stored numeric for used of `max` aggregate function,
alternatively

```
max( cast(value as unsigned) )
```

When you are doing a `MAX`, is a cast to string.
When you are doing comparison, is a cast to numeric.

**Reason?**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max
(it returns the maximum string value)

Comment: Unless a quote has been applied?

Comment: Oh, I had in my mind the string comparison in general. In this case, one of operands in `>` clause is a muneric value, so the second operand is converted to numeric value automatically. Sorry, you are right. I was inattentive.