# Order by numeric values in SQL ascending

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to get this output.

```
MDT 1
MDT 2
MDT 3
MDT 11
MDT 44
```

but, The values are ordered alphabetically, so 123 comes before 2.

example :

```
MDT 1
MDT 11
MDT 156
MDT 2
MDT 3
MDT 303
MDT 44
```

and so on.

I'm use this code, but it seem didn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM file ORDER BY ABS(ID) ASC
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/1868965/1369235

Answer (score 3):

If your ID is always going to contain the prefix as `MDT`, then you can use this, to sort as per your requirement:

```
SELECT * FROM File 
ORDER BY CAST(replace(ID, 'MDT ', '') AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/339cd/1)

Comment: +1 ..i thought that id and mdt are in difference field..but its in same

Comment: MDT as default name for ID. it in the same field

Comment: Then the above query would work as it removes MDT and sorts on the residual integer value converting it into integer.

Comment: Check the SQL Fiddle demo to understand what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Try that snippet

```
SELECT * FROM file ORDER BY ID + 0 ASC
```

Comment: sorry that snippet is to transform the string to an int

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this it will sort based on numeric :

```
select substr(id,4)*1 from file order by substr(id,4)*1
```

It will gives

1 
  2 
  3 
  11
  44 
 ...

If You want all fields try the below query (**"substr(id,4)" or "substr(id,5)"**) based on your string length (ex: id= proj-001911 --> take SUBSTR( id, 6 ) *1) )

```
select * from file order by substr(id,4)*1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM file
ORDER BY CONVERT(SUBSTRING(ID,5),UNSIGNED) ASC
```

`SUBSTRING()` will extract all characters after `'MDT '` and `CONVERT()` will change remaining substring to unsigned integer on which `ORDER BY` is performed

**note** `SUBSTR()` is a synonym for `SUBSTRING()`.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching it out too, but just while reading over here I got it striked in my head and found one solution that if that column is having only numbers as data then you need to make modification in database table and define that column as INT value type, then I am sure what you need will be done.
Eg. `{SELECT * FROM file ORDER BY CONVERT(SUBSTRING(ID,5),UNSIGNED) ASC}` in such case `Convert` is column and that needs to be defined as `INT(5)` will work.