# PHP ORDER BY doesn't do what it's supposed to

Tags: mysql

I am creating some kind of program which first stores numeric values, later on, there will be characters and words in that column so I stored my numbers in a VARCHAR.

Now, I'm using this code:

```
SELECT * FROM biedingen WHERE bod_refferentie=$item ORDER BY bod_bedrag DESC LIMIT 5
```

And the output is:

```
9

27
```

Is there a way to get me to store the numeric values in a varchar, but still be able to order them using kind of the same method as above?

Comment: So what is your problem ? how they listed in your database ?

Comment: Without the PHP code and Database Structure, we can't figure out anything.

Comment: What column is being output?

Comment: @Soheyl The problem is that the numbers aren't ordered in the right way... It's stored as a varchar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Varchar to number conversion for sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868965/varchar-to-number-conversion-for-sorting)

Comment: @AhmadWabbi `biedingen` is the table, not the selected column.

Comment: _Why_ are your numeric values stored as `VARCHAR`?

Comment: @Chris because later on it has to be like that, but for now indeed I could store it otherwise... But I have the answer I was looking for :)

Comment: @CoderYordi, I'm not sure why you think "later on it has to be like that". I can't think of a single good reason to store integer values in `VARCHAR`, and if you think you need to you're probably making a mistake.

Comment: @Chris First this col. holds a numeric value, but it doesn't stay numeric, later on the value will change to words / characters and that's why I store this like that...

Comment: Are you certain that the output you showed us is really from that query?  I would have expected `9 41 27 3`, not the order you showed us.

Comment: @CoderYordi, we're way off-topic, but why are you using one column for multiple purposes? That doesn't sound like a wise move.

Comment: @Chris Indeed way off-topic, and waaay to long to explain (not my idea to do that) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that your `bod_bedrag` column is `varchar` or some other non numeric type.  Hence, MySQL is sorting the column as text rather than numerically.  This explains why single digits appear before double digits, etc.

One workaround here is to cast the `bod_bedrag` column to a numeric type during ordering:

```
SELECT *
FROM biedingen
WHERE bod_refferentie=$item
ORDER BY CAST(bod_bedrag AS SIGNED) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

One nifty alternative recognizes that sorting `varchar` numbers actually works for numbers of the *same* length.  What I mean by this is that if you had `100, 305, 900` and sorted ascending, you would get this order.  Here is another option which avoids the cast:

```
SELECT *
FROM biedingen
WHERE bod_refferentie=$item
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(bod_bedrag) DESC,
         bod_bedrag DESC
LIMIT 5
```