# Natural sort doesn't arrange data properly

Tags: mysql

So I have this set of data for example:

```
+--------------+-----------+
| Name         | Money     |
+--------------+-----------+
| Mickey Mouse | 1,000,780 |
+--------------+-----------+
| Donald Duck  | 1,580,870 |
+--------------+-----------+
| Goofy        | 230,570   |
+--------------+-----------+
```

and when I use:

```
SELECT name, money FROM worth ORDER BY LENGTH(money), money
```

It still displays Goofy over Mickey and Donald.

and when I use:

```
SELECT name, money FROM worth ORDER BY money +0 ASC
```

It still displays Mickey over Donald. Where as Donald should be on top.

I want to arrange it descending order so Donald-Mickey-Goofy.

Comment: What type of column is `money`?

Comment: If column money is a number, do your `ORDER BY DESC`. The higher value will be on top.

Comment: @skelwa its varchar

Comment: @GcalD Fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest storing column 'money' as `Decimal` or `Double` rather than `VARCHAR`.
But for your case, you can order by on length descending first and then money descending.

The below query should work for you.

```
SELECT name, money FROM worth ORDER BY LENGTH(money) desc, money desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Storing money as a varchar is a bad idea for all sorts of reasons - convert it to a more appropriate format if at all possible.

Otherwise, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868965/varchar-to-number-conversion-for-sorting) has an answer.