# How to sort varchar values MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table which has id's(varchar) as

```
-----------------------------------------
ID        |NAME    |COLUMN1  |COLUMN2   |
-----------------------------------------
11.10     |abcd    |New col  | new col  |
11.10(a)  |abcd    |New col  | New Col 2|
11.50     |abcd    |New COl  | New coli | 
11.50(a1) |abcd    |New col  | New Col 2|
11.50(a2) |abcd    |New col  | New Col 2|
11.300(a) |abcd    |New col  | New Col 2|
11.200(a) |abcd    |New col  | New Col 2|
11.100(a) |abcd    |New col  | New Col 2|
11.40(a)  |abcd    |New col  | New Col 2|
```

Now, if I am getting the sorted data using:

```
Select * from table order by length(id) asc,id;
```

I am getting result like

```
11.10
11.50
11.10(a)
11.100(a)
11.200(a)
11.300(a)
11.40(a)
11.50(a)
11.50(a1)
```

But I want the desired output as

```
11.10
11.10(a)
11.40(a)
11.50
11.50(a)
11.50(a2)
11.200(a)
11.300(a)
```

What would be the appropriate query for the same? I have tried it using CAST but I am getting the desired output.

Comment: The desired result doesn't have the same ID values as in the sample data...

Comment: this could be help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868965/varchar-to-number-conversion-for-sorting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL 'Order By' - sorting alphanumeric correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired query maybe this one :

```
select ID           
  from Table_
 order by cast( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, '.',-1), '(', 1) as signed ),
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, '(',-1), ')', 1);
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b9b14/7)

Answer (score 2):

For your example, you can just use `length()`:

```
order by length(id), id
```

A slightly more general approach uses `substring_index()` and implicit conversion:

```
order by substring_index(id, '.', 1) + 0,
         substring_index(id, '.', -1) + 0,
         id
```

Answer (score 0):

`Select Convert(Id,UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS num, col1, col2, col3 from Table
Order By num`
This works as Oracle's To_Number, so I would suggest it will be useful